# Ves Megamenu not open in admin side

Tags: magento2

We have magento 2 site.
We use Ves Megamenu for main menu.
Menu working properly in front side.
But when edit from admin side; menu open; then also open 'Menu Editor'.
But when we click on 'Expand All' button not open any menu.
We get error in consol 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "click: function(){return addItem }"'
Any person help me for solve it.

Comment: Probably best to speak to the extension provider directly. They will be able to advise and provide an update to the module if required.